# How to write multiple record types to a single flat file in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have an xml with multiple element types. Below is a simple xml for prototype. 
The actual xml has more element types.

```
<company>
    <FileHeader>
        <fh_custId>Id</fh_custId>
        <fh_custName>Name</fh_custName>
        <fh_custAge>Age</fh_custAge>
        <fh_dob>DOB</fh_dob>
        <fh_income>Income</fh_income>
    </FileHeader>
    <record refId="1001">
        <name>John</name>
        <age>31</age>
        <dob>31/8/1982</dob>
        <income>200,000</income>
    </record>
</company>
```

I am using StaxEventItemReader with JAXB2Marshaller to read the xml. I want to write to a single fixed size flat file. A FlatFileItemWriter with below settings can only handle one element type - ( in this case the "record" element).
How can I configure other element types as well. For instance "FileHeader" element in the above xml.

```
<property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator">
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="refId, name, age, csvDob, income" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="format" value="%-6.6s%-15.15s%-4.4s%-12.12s%-10.10s%"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a custom [`LineAggregator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/LineAggregator.html) combined with a [`Classifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/classify/class-use/Classifier.html) to dispatch to the right line aggregator.

Comment: Hi Luca, Thanks for your response. As per my understanding we will have two FileItemWriters, one for FileHeader and one for record element. And the Classifier redirects to the correct ItemWriter based on the input object/record type. My question is that can two ItemWriters can write to same file. Does a FileItemWriter open a file every time it writes to it or it keeps the file open until it writes all the data.

Comment: I don't understand why you need two different writers for the same file. FlatFileItemWriter is not thread safe and if you need to write different records to the same file use a custom LineAggregator; IMHO is the safer solution